# Adobe Omniture s_code testing: how to validate?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I would like to deploy an Adobe Omniture s_code update (from 08-28-13) but dev is concerned that we cannot fully test in our staging environment--there is no way that I know of to mimic a referral from Natural Search in stage.

I could see there being a slight risk of breaking variables, but is there a risk of breaking on page javascript when deployed to production?

Does anyone have any suggestions for testing outside production? Or other measures taken to minimize risk?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well in general, it depends on what you are actually testing.. but point in fact, you can override what Adobe looks at for referring url by setting `s.referrer`

Comment: But an alternate way to test new changes in production is if you move to having your code deployed through Adobe's Dynamic Tag Manager. You can make changes within DTM and then you can personally test unpublished changes on your production site with some debug commands (detailed with DTM docs) and if things look shiny to you, you can publish it so changes affect all users in your production environment

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your host file to point your domain to the staging environment. If you are windows:
Find: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (you may have to turn on visibility)

Add and entry like:
mydomain.com 192.168.x.x #just make sure that ip address points to your staging server.
save the file. We call this spoofing.

Open your browser and go to the website and it should be pointed to the staging environment. We use the server variable to distinguish which environment we're in. That is also used to direct the data to the qa report suite so we don't muck up production data. It also keeps data set small so you can validate it in the UI easier.

You can search on Google for your website and then when you click through, you'll land on the staging site.

I'm not sure how to spoof on a mac but I can find out if it's relevant.

The only problems I've seen when upgrading are usually browser related. As long as you test against all your supported browsers, it should be fine.

Hope that helps,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

Further to Brett's message about editing your hosts file, on a Mac (and Linux) this sits under /etc/.

You can also spoof the referrer using a plugin like RefControl for Firefox.